# Text isn't a valid member of ScreenGui DeathScreen

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I tried to make a code that if the player humanoid dies then it connect a function that makes a GUI visible with a death message, but it didn't worked. I did something wrong? (And the player didn't teleport to the part on workspace) Code below:

```
local prl = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = prl.Character or prl.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local lightning = game:GetService("Lighting")
local blur = lightning.Blur
local guideath = prl.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("TelaDeMorte")

char.Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    guideath.TExto.Visible = true   
    for i= 1,10 do
        task.wait(.1)
        guideath.TExto.TextTransparency -= .1
    end
    task.wait(6)
    char:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(workspace.SpawnPoint.CFrame)
    guideath.TExto.TextTransparency = 1
    guideath.TExto.Visible = false
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character is not the same anymore after a respawn. So you'd have to subscribe to the CharacterAdded event instead, like this:

```
local prl = game.Players.LocalPlayer
prl.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
    char:WaitForChild("Humanoid").Died:Connect(function()
        local guideath = prl.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("TelaDeMorte")
        guideath.TExto.Visible = true   
        for i= 1,10 do
            task.wait(.1)
            guideath.TExto.TextTransparency -= .1
        end
        task.wait(6)
        char:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(workspace.SpawnPoint.CFrame)
        guideath.TExto.TextTransparency = 1
        guideath.TExto.Visible = false
    end)    
end)
```